# XScreenSaver: 1-2 seconds delay within which my laptop isn't locked

Tags: arch-linux, screen-lock, lock, xscreensaver

I want my screen to lock automatically and I'm using XScreenSaver. It locks the screen when my  laptop suspends but when open the lid or press the power button, there's a small, 1-2 seconds delay and within it I can see the desktop, that is, it's unlocked. After 1-2 seconds yes, it shows that locked screen.

How can I get rid of that 1-2 seconds delay?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that you are allowing your laptop to suspend before the screensaver kicks in.  So when you open the lid it needs time to check and see if it has been long enough that it should be running.  If it has been, then it starts.

The only solution it going to be to allow the screensaver to lock the unit before closing the screen.

Not to mention keeping other people from touching your stuff.